# Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, path

I'm busy trying to configurate Fouserbundle on Symfony 2.6.9. But doesn't work, i got this message:

**ForbiddenOverwriteException in BaseNode.php line 223: Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.**

(i did configurate, appkernel, config,composer)

**user.php**

```
<?php

namespace FLY\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="FLY_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

**app/Resources/config/security.yml**

```
imports:
- { resource: "@FLYUserBundle/Resources/config/security.yml" }


security:
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

**UserBundle/Resources/config/security.yml**

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

firewalls:

    main:
                pattern: ^/
                form_login:
                    provider: fos_userbundle
                    csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                logout:       true
                anonymous:    true
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
        form_login:
            check_path: /demo/secured/login_check
            login_path: /demo/secured/login
        logout:
            path:   /demo/secured/logout
            target: /demo/
        #anonymous: ~
        #http_basic:
        #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"
```

**app/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
FLY_Platform:
resource: "@FLYPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
prefix:   /


mremi_contact_form:
    resource: "@MremiContactBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml"

genemu_base64:
        resource: "@GenemuFormBundle/Resources/config/routing/base64.xml"

_user_bundle:
    resource: "@UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```

**UserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml**

```
fos_user_security:
resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"


fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error after symfony upgrade

> Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.

In my case I patched old AppKernel.php and had duplicate configuraton load command

```
public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
{
    // this is old code
    $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

    // code above is new and copy-pasted from clean symfony 3.4 install
    $loader->load(function (ContainerBuilder $container) {
        $container->setParameter('container.autowiring.strict_mode', true);
        $container->setParameter('container.dumper.inline_class_loader', true);

        $container->addObjectResource($this);
    });
    $loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
}
```

After removing first one - everything works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error because of having used separate **security.yaml** for dev (`config/dev/security.yaml`) and test (`config/test/security.yaml`) environments (besides `config/security.yaml`).

After removal of these files, error message disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

In symfony, as the error message says, you ca't override most security options. You should define all your security related configuration in `app/config/security.yml`.

Comment: Either that or get rid of the `app/config/security.yml` and remove the `- { resource: security.yml }` from your `app/config/config.yml` to just use your version as the single source of security configuration.

Comment: You must keep `- { resource: security.yml }` in `app/config/config.yml`. What I suggest you is to merge the content of your **app/Resources/config/security.yml** and **UserBundle/Resources/config/security.yml** files in the **app/config/security.yml** file

Comment: Why must you? It's only "best practice". If you want to keep your configuration files anywhere else in the system you can, there's no hard and fast rule about where your config files need to go.

Comment: @Qoop sorry, I missunderstood your comment and thought it was aimeric who comment. Your suggestion is fine :)

Comment: morning, I cut everyrhing that was in : UserBundle/Resources/config/security.yml files  and i past it in app/Resources/config/security.yml  . now UserBundle/Resources/config/security.yml  is empty.  but i still get the same message:  Configuration path "security.access_control" cannot be overwritten. You have to define all options for this path, and any of its sub-paths in one configuration section.

Comment: i'm still busy trying to slove my problem , but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which `security.yml` file is imported in `app/config/config.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

i think the security file that is imported is app/Resources/config/security.yml

this is my app/config/config.yml

```html
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }



framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      ~
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
        #assets_version: SomeVersionScheme
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # handler_id set to null will use default session handler from php.ini
        handler_id:  ~
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true

# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"

# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    bundles:        [ ]
    java: /usr/bin/java
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        cssembed:
          jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/cssembed-0.4.5.jar
        yui_js:
          jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor.jar
        lessphp:
          file: %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/leafo/lessphp/lessc.inc.php
          apply_to: "\.less$"
    assets:
        jquery_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../components/jquery/jquery.min.js'
            filters: [?yui_js]
        bootstrap_js:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/transition.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/alert.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/modal.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/tab.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/popover.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/button.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/collapse.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/carousel.js'
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/js/affix.js'
            filters: [?yui_js]
        bootstrap_less:
            inputs:
                - '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twitter/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less'
            filters: [lessphp,cssembed]

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:  "%mailer_transport%"
    host:       "%mailer_host%"
    encryption: "%mailer_encryption%"
    username:   "%mailer_user%"
    password:   "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

mremi_contact:
    store_data:            false
    contact_class:         Mremi\ContactBundle\Model\Contact

    form:
        type:              mremi_contact
        name:              contact_form
        validation_groups: [Default]
        subject_provider:  mremi_contact.subject_provider.noop
        captcha_type:      genemu_captcha

    email:
        mailer:            mremi_contact.mailer.twig_swift
        from:              [{ address: xxxxxx@gmail.com, name: "Webmaster" } ]
        to:                [{ address: xxxxxx@hotmail.fr } ] # Required
        template:          MremiContactBundle:Contact:email.txt.twig

genemu_form:
    captcha: ~
# fouser Configuration
fos_user:
        db_driver: orm
        firewall_name: main
        user_class: FLY\UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have commented in config_dev.php the line concerning the fos_user db_driver and it helped

Answer (score 0):

Might be a simple reason: i had this error because i backuped the config file security.yaml to _security.yaml. Symfony reads both...